# How To Add A Delay To PhP Header?

Tags: php

How To I Add A Delay To **header('Location: '.$_GET['q']);** In My Code?

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])) {
     if(filter_var($_GET['q'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        header('Location: '.$_GET['q']); 
     }else{
        echo "Invalid URL";
     }

  }
```

Comment: Delay? Delay before *what*?

Comment: are you looking for this `int sleep(int $seconds)`

Comment: where would i add that at i am new to php

Comment: i am looking to add a delay to that one line of code but for the rest of the page to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sleep` function will block code to be executed after.

Maybe what you are looking for is `html meta tag refresh`

Like this:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com/mypage">
```

where 5 is measure in seconds.

Comment: Yes i see how i can edit this to fit my code thank you very much!